# Code generating SOAP Web Service Proxy objects yourself - C#/.NET 3.5/T4

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, code-generation, t4

Is there a framework or code already available that will give me more control over the code that gets generated based off my web references?

I'm working at a new company. And the Web Services Proxies are all self contained in their own assembly. I would really rather generate this whole project. Every time they change something on the Services-side (Java) the WSDL references have to be dropped and re-added. 
(I can't figure out what those guys are doing on their end that messes with the WSDL bad enough that this needs to be done so much)
Their are 10 of these references. I'd rather codegen the whole thing at compile time. Every time.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the [ServiceDescriptionImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescriptionimporter.aspx)